# Are 20% of cleaners, store packers, and food and hospitality workers in Australia on temporary visas?

Tags: politics, immigration, australia

In a recent [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/malcolmrobertsonenation/), [Australian Senator Malcolm Roberts](https://www.aph.gov.au/Senators_and_Members/Parliamentarian?MPID=266524) makes the claim that 20% of Australia's cleaners, store packers and food hospitality workers are on temporary migrant visas.

> According to a report from the Australian Population Research
>   Institute, almost a fifth of the ­nation’s cleaners, store packers,
>   and food and hospitality workers are on temporary migrant visas.

This claim refers to a report that I would like to see.

[image: Image with claim of 20 percent of low skilled workers]

Comment: Here's the report https://tapri.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Jobs-and-growth-final-Nov-25.pdf

Answer (score 6):

The claims seems to be roughly correct in the sense that the TAPRI report has this data; from the [report](https://tapri.org.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Jobs-and-growth-final-Nov-25.pdf) linked by Legion600:

> Table 2   shows   that    at  the time    of  Census  in  2016    these   temporary   migrants    constituted a
>   significant share   of  all those   employed    in  the occupations listed. For example,    this    amounted
>   to  19  per cent    of  all those   employed    as  cleaners    and laundry workers and 18  per cent    of
>   hospitality workers.
>
> [image]

I would also note a [SMH article](https://www.smh.com.au/business/the-economy/populist-drum-beats-wrong-numbers-drive-our-migration-debate-20180404-p4z7qk.html) that says regarding the TAPRI leader (and co-author of this report):

> Bob Birrell, a constant critic of our immigration program through his Australian Population Research Institute [...]

and that Birrell's viewpoint often/mainly is that Australia's immigration program is a failure at attracting the highly skilled...  (from the same TAPRI report)

> Migrants  on  temporary   visas   now dominate    the 
>   migrant flow    entering    the Australian  labour  market. As  a   consequence Australia’s migration program   is  now primarily   low skilled,    rather  than    high    skilled.

This conclusion may not be correct, according to others... quoted by SMH.

Also, the 2016 data may not have that much relevance anymore given the [2017 overhaul](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2017/apr/19/peter-dutton-defends-decision-to-scrap-457-visa-program) of the temporary work vista system. [According](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2019/jul/15/temporary-skilled-migration-has-not-undercut-australian-jobs-or-conditions-report-finds) to statististics for the updated system:

> The top four occupations of those who were granted visas in 2017-2018 were developer programmer, ICT business analyst, university lecturer and cook.

The TAPRI report was written in 2019 and references some 2019 data (but not by category of employment). Why that is so, is left for the reader to decide, but I suspect it's because the newer data didn't fit their narrative.